# Using a dropdown on a static webpage as a DataSource in C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, datasource

I know this is a terrible way of doing things, but it's for an internal app where security is no issue.

Basically, an old group created a php page with a drop down and this drop down is populated with entries from a DB. The DB owner is currently absent and for the sake of time, I would just need something that turns the entries in that drop down, always at the same url with the same ID every load into a List. Is there a quick, painless way to do this in .NET?

Comment: Can you get to the database connection info in the php source file or do you not have access?

Comment: No access - I only have access to the rendered page --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your only option is to try and parse the html.  While there is no great way to do this you can fetch the page with a `WebRequest` then try something like the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse out your list.